# How to assign variables in twig?

Tags: php, twig, smarty

Im migrating my code from smarty to twig

but I dont seem to find how to do this in twig

smarty:

```
 $smarty->assign('Config',$Core->settings);
```

how can I do this in Twig ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use 'set'. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html
Then you would have to pass in `$Core->settings` as a variable from your controller like so:

```
return $this->render('my_template.html.twig', array(
        'core_settings' => $Core->settings,
));
```

Then in `my_template.html.twig` you would use set like this:

```
{% set 'Config' = core_settings %}
```

I'm not sure if that works for you, Twig is different than smarty (I'm not very familar with smarty) but Twig is powerful.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct answer with the checkmark please.